# Google Calendar Alerts have quit on Windows and Android

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, calendar

I'm getting email notifications, but no pop-ups on Windows-10 desktop (in Chrome), and nothing on my Android smart phone.  I'm afraid to missing meetings now after relying on this feature.

My Primary Calendar settings are as follows: 
[image]

The General/Event Settings are: 
[image]

Comment: We will be unable to answer your question with regards to your Android device.  That will require it's own question at [Android Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Ok, but it seems to be indicative a common issue; they both used to work.

Comment: It does not really matter.  How you resolve this problem on Windows will not be applicable to an Android device.  This is under the assumption it's a setting with the device that is the problem instead of a Google Calendar configuration issue (i.e. would belong on Web Applications Stack Exchange).